# Binding a button to a function inside a for loop in vue js

Tags: vue.js

Basically i am trying make multiple buttons for each row and when the button is clicked a function fetch value according to the key

```
<tr v-for="csv in parse_csv">
<td v-for="key in parse_header">
{{csv[key]}}
</td>
<button class="btn btn-info" @change="getjson(csv)">Register</button>
</tr>
```

So when the button is clicked the value is fetched from the json according to the key.
and that value is passed to the method but the above code doesn't work .

Comment: can you provide the script

Comment: Why is there `@change` on a button?

Comment: sorry it was supposed to be @click

Comment: got it thanks Estus Flask